# MySQL Workbench Data Export error. "Error executing task [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a problem to export a small database using MySQL Workbench's Data Export function on Windows 10.
Previously I have had no problems exporting and importing databases, although after this happened I have changed the security of the server to legacy to get it working with phpMyAdmin using the MySQL Workbench Installer, which I have been unable to change back as when trying to execute the change I got an error stating the installer was unable to create the temporary user (running this as administrator didn't help).

Since then I have also updated MySQL Workbench, the server, and the rest of the components that were installed with it, which seems to have gotten rid of the MySQL Workbench Installer application, as such i am unable to provide the exact error it gave regarding being unable to create the temporary user.
I'm not 100% sure if the above is relevant to the issue but it does seem like it could be related.

The issue that I'm trying to fix is that MySQL Workbench will not export any (or all of) the databases I have set up to a self contained file. The error I keep getting is below:

`09:47:47 Dumping va_form (all tables)
Error executing task [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'D:\Mike\Desktop\Dump20190226.sql'
09:47:47 Export of D:\Mike\Desktop\Dump20190226.sql has finished`
I was previously getting a similar error about access denied, which then lead me to change the default dump directory to my desktop, as I'm only going to need to dump files occasionally and sort and send them elsewhere straight away.
I have also tried disabling column-statistics and lock-tables although this has had no effect.

As you can see, at the start of the directory it's trying to dump to it says "u'D:\\" - I am not sure if this leading u is significant, although it is not there in the directory I have specified to dump the file to.

I'm hoping someone here has some insight into this issue, I have no idea why MySQL Workbench's installer was refusing to make the temporary user (even when being run as administrator) and why I cannot find the installer now, as well as the obvious problem of why MySQL workbench is unable to create the file to dump anywhere on the system.
Thanks very much for your time reading this.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably an issue with a recent update of Windows Defender, not with MySQL.

Try to save your dump to folders located somewhere else than Desktop or Documents (I usually send them directly to a cloud service integrated with my OS). If this works, you just need to add an exception for MySQL in Windows Defender.